# Difference between lag plot and acf plot

Tags: r, time-series

I am not sure if I understand the difference clearly between ggAcf and gglagplot. Specifically, from lag.plot documentation in R

'Plot time series against lagged versions of themselves. Helps visualizing ‘auto-dependence’ even when auto-correlations vanish.'

In summary, I think I am not very clear about how to interpret gglagplot, but I think I have some fair understanding about ggAcf

Comment: See https://www.otexts.org/fpp2/lag-plots.html and https://www.otexts.org/fpp2/autocorrelation.html

Comment: The correlation you can see in a lag plot will be a point in the acf plot

Answer (score 1):

gglagplot function plots a series of scatterplots between the timeseries and the lagged values of the timeseries. For example consider the following time series:

`> ts1 <- ts(seq(0.1,0.9, by = 0.01), frequency = 7)
Time Series:
Start = c(1, 1) 
End = c(12, 4) 
Frequency = 7 
 [1] 0.10 0.11 0.12 0.13 0.14 0.15 0.16 0.17 0.18 0.19 0.20 0.21 0.22 0.23 0.24
[16] 0.25 0.26 0.27 0.28 0.29 0.30 0.31 0.32 0.33 0.34 0.35 0.36 0.37 0.38 0.39
[31] 0.40 0.41 0.42 0.43 0.44 0.45 0.46 0.47 0.48 0.49 0.50 0.51 0.52 0.53 0.54
[46] 0.55 0.56 0.57 0.58 0.59 0.60 0.61 0.62 0.63 0.64 0.65 0.66 0.67 0.68 0.69
[61] 0.70 0.71 0.72 0.73 0.74 0.75 0.76 0.77 0.78 0.79 0.80 0.81 0.82 0.83 0.84
[76] 0.85 0.86 0.87 0.88 0.89 0.90`

A lagplot with `lags = 1` for this time series will be plot using x-axis as `ts1` and y-axis as `ts1[-1]`.

Following code will plot the following combination of points `(0.10,0.11), (0.11,0.12),(0.12,0.13) and so on ...`

`> gglagplot(ts1, lags = 1)`